# How to store "1/01/1900 3:54:32 a.m." in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm saving data from a CSV file into a MySQL database. I'm using Laravel and trying to decide what is the best way to store such data. See: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns. Do I use `timestamp`? Would I lose anything if I just stored it as a string?

Comment: how about a `datetime` with '1900-01-01 03:54:32' going into it. Don't go the string route. You will lose all functionality of datemath functions

Comment: Indeed mysql datetime does not have the Unix timestamps limitations. Any year from 1000 to 9999 is acceptable.

Comment: Although `w3school` is not what they recommended here have a look at this link to convert to `MySQL` date format http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `datetime`

The advantage of `datetime` over string is that it will be stored more efficiently and you will be able to query this data with more tools

[Read more in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)

Comment: And I can store `1/01/1900 3:54:32 a.m.` as in in that column?

Comment: Yes. You will need to use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). And the `a.m` is redundant